# GEDCOM to HTML and RDF

Tags: html, rdf, genealogy, gedcom

I was wondering if anyone knew of an application that would take a GEDCOM genealogy file and convert it to HTML format for viewing and publishing on the web.  I'd like to have separate html files for each individual and perhaps additional files for other content as well.  I know there are some tools out there but I was wondering if anyone used any tools and could advise on this.  I'm not sure what format to look for such applications.  They could be Python or php files that one can edit, or even JavaScript (maybe) or just executable files.

The next issue might be appropriate for a topic in itself.  Export of GEDCOM to RDF.  My interest here would be to align the information with specific vocabularies, such as BIO or REL which both are extended from FOAF.

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several years ago, I created a simple Java program to turn gedcom into xml.  I then used xslt to generate html and rdf.  The html I generate is pretty rudimentary, so it would probably be better to look elsewhere for that, but the rdf might be useful to you:

http://jay.askren.net/Projects/SemWeb/

Comment: I had found your site in my research

Answer (score 2):

Like Rob Kam said, Ged2Html was the most popular such program for a long time.

[GRAMPS](http://gramps-project.org/) can also create static HTML sites and has the advantage of being free software and having a native XML format which you could easily modify to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of these. All listed at http://www.cyndislist.com/gedcom/gedcom-to-web-page-conversion/

[Ged2html](http://www.starkeffect.com/ged2html/) used to be the most popular and most versatile, but is now no longer being developed. It's an executable, with output customisable through its own scripting syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Family Historian http://www.family-historian.co.uk will create exactly what you are looking for, eg one file per person using the built in Web Site creator.  As will a couple of the other Major genealogy packages. I have not seen anything for the RDF part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have since tried to produce a Genealogy application using Semantic MediaWiki - MediaWiki, the software behind Wikipedia, and Semantic MediaWiki includes various extensions related to the Semantic Web.  I thought it is very easy to use with the forms and the ability to upload a GEDCOM but some feedback from people into genealogy said that it appeared too technical and didn't seem to offer anything new.

So, now the issue is whether to stay with MediaWiki and make it more user friendly or create an entirely new application that allows for adding and updating data in a triple store as well as displaying.  I'm not sure how to generate a family tree graphical view of the data, like on sites like ancestry.com, where one can click on a box to see details about the person and update that info or one could click on a right or left arrow around a box to navigate the tree.   The data comes from SPARQL queries sent to the data set/triple store both when displaying the initial view and when navigating the tree, where an Ajax call is needed to get more data.
Bruce

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/elliotchance/gedcom) is pretty good, but as of right now doesn't support [viewing the file as a tree](https://github.com/elliotchance/gedcom/issues/330). [This](https://github.com/bartfeenstra/betty) is also pretty cool.